# haproxy path depth based acl

Tags: acl, haproxy

I am using HAproxy to do some loadbalancing.

The requested is to:

- Use server pool `old_servers_pool` when `http://www.myproject.com:8080/*/*.pdf`  in
  other words when path depth is 1 and suffix is .pdf
- Use server pool `new_servers_pool` when anything else under `http://www.myproject.com:8080`

I tried in my haproxy.config  somehting like:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
    maxconn 200
    user    root
    group   root


defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout http-request 5s


backend old-servers
   http-check expect status 200
   balance roundrobin
   server server_static_old_1 192.168.1.155:80

backend new-servers
   http-check expect status 200
   balance roundrobin
   server server_static_old_1 192.167.1.1:80

frontend public
   bind *:8080
acl old_lst  path_reg -i  /.*/.*\.pdf
use_backend old-servers if old_lst
default_backend new-servers
```

But it does not work.

Also some tests with one of the following definitions of acl each time:

```
acl old_lst   path_reg -i /*/*\.pdf
use_backend old-servers if { path_reg -i /.*/.*(.pdf) }
acl old_lst  path_reg -i  /.*/.*\.pdf
acl old_lst  path_reg -i  /.*$/.*\.pdf
acl old_lst  path_reg -i  /.*/.*\.pdf$
acl old_lst  path_reg -i  /.*/  AND   path_end -i .pdf
acl old_lst path_reg -i  /([a-z0-9\-\.]*)/([a-z\-]*)\.pdf
```

But unfortunatelly, nothing works.

Any ideas??

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be accomplished with a combination of ACLs, one for the beginning of the path and one for the end.

`acl old_lst path_beg -m reg ^(\/[\w\.-]+)\/`

should create an ACL that accepts a single path depth. 
[Check it out the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/vS7xB9/1)

The regex looks at the start of the line for a /, a capture group comprised letters and numbers, plus . and - (this may not cover all cases), followed by another slash.

`acl pdf path_end .pdf` should create an ACL for all things ending in .pdf.

Put them together

`use_backend old-servers if old_lst pdf`

I answered because I came across your question while searching for the answer to a similar ACL problem, but I did not go as far as to test the above, so good luck, I hope this helps!

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7